# Change delimiter and restructure file with bash commands

Tags: bash

I have a huge data file with two types of data. One like this:

```
$1 = {281.95849185110393, 336.27948244115851, 279.66401201832105, 328.55431033520654, 278.06462879690559, 325.86321739815691}
```

Where I would like to remove `$1 = {` `}` and put all the values in the file as a single column:

```
281.95849185110393
336.27948244115851
279.66401201832105
328.55431033520654
278.06462879690559
325.86321739815691
```

The other data type is:

```
$2 = {{-3691.7051951760536, 27.470513409955384, 25006.562760859793}, {-49869.618501644189, -7688.9232143687505, 241816.98281996409}}
```

I would like to remove the `$2 = {` `}` and transform each `{n1,n2,n2}` into `(n1 n2 n3)` and again into a single column.

So the final output would be:

```
(-3691.7051951760536 27.470513409955384 25006.562760859793)
(-49869.618501644189 -7688.9232143687505 241816.98281996409)
```

Which Bash function is able to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easy to do with bash but not too hard with `sed` although the command is ugly.

```
sed -e '/$1/s/}$//g' -e '/$1/s/, /\n/g' -e 's/$1 = {//' \
    -e '/$2/s/}}/)/' -e '/$2/s/}, {/)\n(/g' -e 's/$2 = {{/(/' filename
```

`sed` is running six expressions here. The first three apply only when the line starts with "$1" and, in order, removes the final }, then replaces ", " with a newline, then deletes "$1 = {". The second three works on the $2 lines, replacing the final }} with }, replacing "}, " with "}\n", and then deleting "$2 = {".

Tested with GNU sed v4.2.2.

Comment: just changed the `$1` to `$[0-9]*` for a general number!

Comment: @mysticsnake Does that still work on your input file? In your example, $1 ended with `}` and this was removed. In $2, the trailing `}}` was replaced with `)`. I don't see how changing the first check to any number preserves this substitution. However, if this works for you, consider accepting the answer so that it is returned more often in a search.

Comment: it works. in the `sed` command I did the change. So far it worked on arbitrary numbers